# How to get new data after data change in SQLite using viewmodel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

How to get new data after data change in SQLite using viewmodel ?

FavoriteViewModel.Kt

```
class FavoriteViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private var favoriteEventList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Favorite>>()

    init {
        favoriteEventList = getFavoriteEvent(application)
    }

    fun getFavorite(): LiveData<MutableList<Favorite>> = favoriteEventList

    private fun getFavoriteEvent(context: Context): MutableLiveData<MutableList<Favorite>> {
        val favoriteList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Favorite>>()
        val favorites: MutableList<Favorite> = mutableListOf()
        favorites.clear()
        context.database.use {
            val result = select(Favorite.TABLE_FAVORITE)
            val favorite = result.parseList(classParser<Favorite>())
            favorites.addAll(favorite)
            favoriteList.value = favorites
        }
        return favoriteList
    }

    fun removeFromFavorite(context: Context, param: String) {
        try {
            context.database.use {
                delete(
                    Favorite.TABLE_FAVORITE, "(${Favorite.EVENT_ID} = {id})",
                    "id" to param
                )
            }
            showToast(context, "Removed from favorite")
        } catch (e: SQLiteConstraintException) {
            showToast(context, "Error : ${e.localizedMessage}")
        }
    }
}
```

FavoriteFragment.Kt

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val favoriteViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this)[FavoriteViewModel::class.java]
        favoriteViewModel.getFavorite().observe(this, Observer {
            progressBar.gone()
            favoriteList.clear()
            favoriteList.addAll(it)
        })
    }
```

i try show and delete data from SQlite using "Anko SQLite" it's work. But, after delete some data, i don't get new data from SQLite. So, in FavoriteFragment just show old data. I must reopen FavoriteFragment for show new data

Comment: you initialize live data as a class member not inside the method and always observe the same livedata

Comment: @Raghunandan How to do that?
i try return Livedata in method. But, not work. i get old data
`private fun getFavoriteEvent(context: Context): LiveData<List<Favorite>> {
        val favoriteList = MutableLiveData<List<Favorite>>()
        context.database.use {
            val result = select(Favorite.TABLE_FAVORITE)
            val favorite = result.parseList(classParser<Favorite>())
            favoriteList.value = favorite
        }
        return favoriteList
    }`

Comment: you need to observe the same livedata in your case you initialize livedata in a method and that means every time you call that method you are creating a new livedata. if you use room and livedata whenever there is a change in database you will have livedata observing those changes.

Answer (score 0):

put this code on Delete button click listener  instead of onResume

```
val favoriteViewModel =
        ViewModelProviders.of(this)[FavoriteViewModel::class.java]
    favoriteViewModel.getFavorite().observe(this, Observer {
        progressBar.gone()
        favoriteList.clear()
        favoriteList.addAll(it)
    })
```

Comment: delete button in different Fragment (favorite Detail) sir. So, i want after delete and close favorite detail Fragment. Data in FavoriteFragment will change to new data